# No tables found and merged column text when extracting data from this PDF using Camelot

Tags: python, pdf-parsing, python-camelot

I get a `UserWarning: No tables found on page-1` when I try to extract tables from the attached PDF . However, when I looked at the extracted data, some of the column text was merged into a single column.”

[image]

I am using [Camelot](https://github.com/socialcopsdev/camelot) to parse these PDFs

Steps to reproduce:  `camelot --output m27.csv --format csv stream m27.pdf`

Here is a link to PDF that I am trying to parse: https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java/blob/master/src/test/resources/technology/tabula/m27.pdf

Comment: Try SLICEmyPDF in 1 of the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56017702/how-to-extract-table-from-pdf-in-python/72414309#72414309

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PDF just contains instructions to place a character at an x,y coordinate on a 2-D plane, retaining no knowledge of words, sentences or tables.

Camelot uses [PDFMiner](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer) under the hood to group characters into words and words into sentences. Sometimes when the characters are too close, PDFMiner can group characters belonging to different words into a single one.

Since the characters in your PDF table are placed very close, they are being merged into a single word and hence Camelot isn't able to detect the columns correctly. You can specify column separators to get the table out in this case. To get the x-coordinates of column separators you can check out the [visual debugging guide](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#visual-debugging). Additionally, you can specify `split_text=True` to cut the word along the column separators you've specified. Here's the code (I got the x-coordinates by creating a matplotlib plot of the text in the PDF using `$ camelot stream -plot text m27.pdf`):

Using CLI:

`$ camelot --output m27.csv --format csv -split stream -C 72,95,209,327,442,529,566,606,683 m27.pdf`

Using API:

```
>>> import camelot
>>> tables = camelot.read_pdf('m27.pdf', flavor='stream', columns=['72,95,209,327,442,529,566,606,683'], split_text=True)
```

Comment: i have simillar problem, but my pdf is image of table, and this large table have each line in different size, i have also receiving an error: `UserWarning: No tables found on page-1 ` any ide how to solve it? do you think its connected with those line sizes?